# PHP - How can I retrieve data from a database and display it in a form and make changes to it and update it?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm new to PHP and I've been trying out PHP for a while. I have been able to retrieve data from my database and viewed it in a form but I cant seem to update it when I try to change any of the values. My code is below. Ive been trying a few things so sorry for the bad code

```
<form action="user.php" method="POST">
                <h4>Edit Account</h4>
                <input type="text" name="editstudent_number" placeholder="Enter Student Number">
                <input type="submit" name="editaccount" value="Search"><br>
                <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['editaccount'])){
                        $GLOBALS['editstudent_number'] = $_POST['editstudent_number'];
                        $editstudent = $GLOBALS['editstudent_number'];

                        $edit_sql = "SELECT username, student_number, email, password, progress, rank FROM users WHERE student_number = '$editstudent'";
                        $edit_query = mysqli_query($conn, $edit_sql);
                        $edit_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_query);

                        $username = $edit_fetch['username'];
                        $student_number = $edit_fetch['student_number'];
                        $email = $edit_fetch['email'];
                        $password = $edit_fetch['password'];
                        $progress = $edit_fetch['progress'];
                        $rank = $edit_fetch['rank'];

                        echo "<input type='text' name='username' value='$username' /><br>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='student_number' value='$student_number' /><br>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='email' value='$email' /><br>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='password' value='$password' /><br>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='progress' value='$progress' /><br>";
                        echo "<input type='text' name='rank' value='$rank' />";
                        echo "<input type='submit' name='editaccount' value='Save changes' />";                 
                    }

                        $GLOBALS['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                        $GLOBALS['student_number'] = $_POST['student_number'];
                        $GLOBALS['email'] = $_POST['email'];
                        $GLOBALS['password'] = $_POST['password'];
                        $GLOBALS['progress'] = $_POST['progress'];
                        $GLOBALS['rank'] = $_POST['rank'];

                        $edit_username = $GLOBALS['username'];
                        $edit_student_number = $GLOBALS['student_number'];
                        $edit_email = $GLOBALS['email'];
                        $edit_password = $GLOBALS['password'];
                        $edit_progress = $GLOBALS['progress'];
                        $edit_rank = $GLOBALS['rank'];

                    if (isset($_POST['editaccount'])){
                        $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='$edit_username', student_number='$edit_student_number', email='$edit_email', password='$edit_password', progress='$edit_progress', rank='$edit_rank' WHERE student_number = '$editstudent'";
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                     
                    }
                ?>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Search button and Save change button have same name, which might cause the conflict.

Search

```
<input type="submit" name="editaccount" value="Search"><br>
```

Save

```
<input type='submit' name='editaccount' value='Save changes' />
```

And looks at how you have SAME `if (isset($_POST['editaccount'])){` two times in the codes.

Change the names.

And also, use different FORM for the Search and the Update.

This is your codes that I have cleaned up a bit, and hopefully working.

```
<h4>Edit Account</h4>

<!-- search form -->
<form action="user.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="editstudent_number" placeholder="Enter Student Number">
  <input type="submit" name="searchstudent" value="Search"><br>
</form>

<!-- update form -->
<form action="user.php" method="POST">

<?php

  if (isset($_POST['editaccount']))
  {
      $edit_username = $_POST['username'];
      $edit_student_number = $_POST['student_number'];
      $edit_email = $_POST['email'];
      $edit_password = $_POST['password'];
      $edit_progress =$_POST['progress'];
      $edit_rank = $_POST['rank'];

      $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='$edit_username', student_number='$edit_student_number', email='$edit_email', password='$edit_password', progress='$edit_progress', rank='$edit_rank' WHERE student_number = '$edit_student_number'";
      $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                     
  }

  if (isset($_POST['searchstudent']))
  {
      $editstudent = $_POST['editstudent_number'];

      $edit_sql = "SELECT username, student_number, email, password, progress, rank FROM users WHERE student_number = '$editstudent'";
      $edit_query = mysqli_query($conn, $edit_sql);
      $edit_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_query);

      $username = $edit_fetch['username'];
      $student_number = $edit_fetch['student_number'];
      $email = $edit_fetch['email'];
      $password = $edit_fetch['password'];
      $progress = $edit_fetch['progress'];
      $rank = $edit_fetch['rank'];

      echo "<input type='text' name='username' value='$username' /><br>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='student_number' value='$student_number' /><br>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='email' value='$email' /><br>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='password' value='$password' /><br>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='progress' value='$progress' /><br>";
      echo "<input type='text' name='rank' value='$rank' />";
      echo "<input type='submit' name='editaccount' value='Save changes' />";                 
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Please search the student number to update the details.";
  }

?>

</form>
```

Just a note, you SHOULD NOT allow user to UPDATE the PRIMARY KEY of your table. In your case, the Student Number is the primary keys, yet you allow user to update it. This will causes conflicts and errors in the update process.

Comment: Agreed on the same name attributes. However, they can keep what they have now, they would just need to add an additional statement. I.e.: `if (isset($_POST['editaccount']) && $_POST['editaccount']=='Save changes' )` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh yes you are right about that, totally forgot about that. Thank you

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the error, just added the form tags around the output and went on from there.

Comment: Great. please accept the answer if you think it useful.